# How can I use Python requests library with IBMWatson API?

Tags: python, post, python-requests, format, ibm-watson

I am currenlty thinkering with the IBMWatson Natural Language Understanding API.
In the official tutorial page it shows the basic curl command to use the api as follows:

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{
  "url": "http://newsroom.ibm.com/Guerbet-and-IBM-Watson-Health-Announce-Strategic-Partnership-for-Artificial-Intelligence-in-Medical-Imaging-Liver",
  "features": {
    "sentiment": {},
    "categories": {},
    "concepts": {},
    "entities": {},
    "keywords": {}
  }
}' \
"{url}/v1/analyze?version=2019-07-12"
```

The command basicly analyzes the page provided in the url key of data parameter and returns an analysis.
I want to do the same action using Python's requests library, however I am new to it. As far as I've gathered from the web the following format should correspond to the same request:

```
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

features = {"sentiment": {},"categories": {},"concepts": {},"entities": {},"keywords": {}}

myData ={
    "url": "http://newsroom.ibm.com/Guerbet-and-IBM-Watson-Health-Announce-Strategic-Partnership-for-Artificial-Intelligence-in-Medical-Imaging-Liver",
    "features": features
 }

d = requests.post(
                auth=('apikey','7LNEjCMvP6ZcNShjAkjPob7QSCfIHeZMQkn4Ho3dQgte'),
                headers=headers,
                data=myData,
                url='https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2019-07-12'
            )
```

However, the server responds with a "400", which I believe is caused by an error in my format.

- I have tested editing my apikey, which resulted in Error code 401 "Unauthorized", as expected. So, I know that I can access the server and get authenticated with my key.
- I have tested removing the "headers" parameter, which resulted in 415 "Unsupported Media Type", so the return type has to be JSON I guess.

I am not sure on what I'm doing wrong, and appreciate any kind of help. Thanks.

Comment: It is very unusual to see the url not being passed in as the 1st parameter or as a keyed parameter in `requests` - https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Python SDK examples for [`analyze`](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding/natural-language-understanding?code=python#analyze-text) and [Text analytics features](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding/natural-language-understanding?code=python#text-analytics-features)
 in the API reference. They might help.